# query in ms access for pulling data by giving parameters for current date

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT t1.[Ticket Number], t1.[Time Received], t1.[Time Read], t1.[Time Replied], t1.[Replied By], t1.[Called Customer?], t1.[Call Duration], t1.[Email Duration], t1.[General Issue]
FROM t1
WHERE [DDATE]=[GETDATE()];
```

Here `DDATE` is a field with dates that will be entered.

My query has to pull details for that day only, `t1` is the table.

So how can i make this query to take todays date as parameter automatically?

I have made forms and tables and query in MS Access 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Date() as long as there is no time element to DDate.

```
SELECT t1.[Ticket Number], t1.[Time Received], 
   t1.[Time Read], t1.[Time Replied], 
   t1.[Replied By], t1.[Called Customer?], 
   t1.[Call Duration], t1.[Email Duration], t1.[General Issue] 
FROM t1 
WHERE [DDATE]=DATE()
```

Comment: I've got another query like, when i load the form in msaccess it displays some values from the database how can we keep it blank or novalue?

Comment: You want a form to enter data? There is a property for that either in OpenForm `DoCmd.OpenForm "name", , , , acFormAdd` or in form design.

Comment: No sorry for the confussion

Comment: when we open the form it has first value which is from the database.Any way to keep the fields blank with no data it when we open the form?

Comment: Using acFormAdd the form will open at a blank new record. A form that is simply blank is more of a problem. You can create a one-record table with a single empty record and use that as the recordsource, simply removing the record source will not look good, or you can create an unbound form.